# NSAttributedString background color is not solid when other attributes are applied

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I want to make several changes to `UILabel` text style by using `NSAttributedString`:

1. Part of the string must have a solid `backgroundColor`;
2. Some parts of the string must have a different `font`;
3. Some parts of the string must have a different `foregroundColor`;

But when i made these changes, i ran into the problem that `backgroundColor` has some spacing (vertical lines in the image) between (i think) other attributes (`font`/`foregroundColor`).

[image]

*(See the [full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8KJg.png))*

How can i fixed that?

Swift Playground code:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let label = UILabel()
label.backgroundColor = .black
let text = "Hello + World!"
let nsText = NSString(string: text)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

attributedString.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.systemCyan, range: nsText.range(of: "Hello + Wo"))

attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100.0), range: nsText.range(of: "Hello"))

attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.systemPurple, range: nsText.range(of: " + "))
attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80.0), range: nsText.range(of: " + "))

attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range: nsText.range(of: "World!"))
attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 44.0), range: nsText.range(of: "World!"))

label.attributedText = attributedString
label.sizeToFit()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = label
```

Comment: Did you try adding the background attribute in the initializer using `attributes:`?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The string is rendering exactly as you have asked it to. What exactly do you want to change? You gave `"Hello + Wo"` a background color of cyan in the first attribute.

Comment: @Sulthan, no, because i want only part of my string to have a background color and `.init` will apply it to the whole string.

Comment: @liquid, please, see the full size image first. I wrote the question pretty clearly: i need a solid background color with no spaces.

Comment: Oh, I thought you drew the black lines in there for illustration purposes like you did the red arrows.

Comment: No, I made `backgroundColor` of the label black to make it easier to see that spacing is really there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an attribute called `expansion` that adjusts the font's expansion factor using a float value. The problem only occurs where two ranges with different font sizes meet, and this is a graphical rendering issue that cannot be overridden. But if you explicitly zero out the expansion factor, or even apply a small negative value, the gaps will not be noticeable.

```
attributedString.addAttribute(.expansion, value: NSNumber(value: 0), range: nsText.range(of: "Hello + World!"))
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1524652-expansion?language=objc__5